# How to Install Sklearn in windows syste,

Tags: python

I am trying to install the Sklearn python library using

```
    pip install sklearn
```

in cmd terminal in windows 8.
its shows no error. but when i am executing my code it gives error stating

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Dipak\Desktop\k means.py", line 5, in <module>
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 134, in 
    <module>
    from .base import clone
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 10, in 
    <module>
    from scipy import sparse
    ImportError: No module named scipy
```

i googled a lot.

Comment: Have you tried installing scipy? For Windows, you should be able to install a binary version of it from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ - although note that you'll also need to install Numpy before Scipy. (There are Numpy binary versions on that page as well.)

Comment: I installed the numpy. and got the success message.. stating          requirements already satisfied